# Plesk 12.5 и Connection refused

Tags: nginx, apache2

Здравствуйте!
Есть проблема с Plesk 12.5 и с одним из доменов. Если я, например, через ssh на сервере на котором расположен сайт ввожу "curl https://sitename.ru/ " то получаю ошибку  "port 443: Connection refused"
Сам сайт открывается из мира, это единственный домен на сервере для которого не могу достучаться, с другими доменами таких проблем нет

Посмотрел: на других серверах где установлен plesk
"curl -v 127.0.0.1" Все домены являются доменами по умолчанию.

- Rebuilt URL to: 127.0.0.1/
- Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
- Trying 127.0.0.1...
- connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
- Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
- Closing connection 0

---

curl -v https://sitename.ru/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying ::1...
* connect to ::1 port 443 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 443 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.1.1...
* connect to 127.0.1.1 port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to travel-rich.ru port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to travel-rich.ru port 443: Connection refused

Решено: Добавил  в /etc/hosts строчку 111.11.1.111.1    sitename.ru

Comment: уточните (прямо в вопросе, нажав [edit]): 1. в какой ip-адрес резолвится имя *sitename.ru* на этой машине. 2. какой процесс на этой машине слушает 443-й порт. 3. как сконфигурирована (в отношении прослушиваемых адресов/портов) программа, запускающая этот процесс. 4. пусты ли на этой машине таблицы *netfilter-а*. если не пусты, приложите вывод `sudo iptables-save`.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно открыть порт 443 на Localhost. У вас получается так, что внешний интерфес открыт, а 127.0.0.1 - нет